# Bootstrap navbar won't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My page, containing a bootstrap navbaar, shows a togglebutton for the menulinks when viewed in smal window. Hiiting this buttons shows the dropdown containing the menuitems but after pressing the togglebutton again it won't close...

Anyone know why?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Loket BWL Rapportage</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bwl.css" type="text/css"/>

    </head>

    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <img class="imgLogo" src="Images/arnhemlogo.png" alt="arnhem" />

        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a href="#">testlink 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">testlink 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td class = "header">Onderwerp</td>
          <td class = "header">Gegevens</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </table>
      <!--<br/>
        <div style="font-size:12px"><b><a href="metainfo.htm" target="blank">Meta-informatie</a></b></div>-->
    </div>
    </body>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" />
  <script language="JavaScript" src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js" />

  </html>
```

Comment: sorry, the page contains 2 script references aswell ( offcourse)

Comment: And what are they? Have an edit of your answer.

Comment: <script language="JavaScript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" />
  <script language="JavaScript" src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js" />

Comment: Please edit your question inserting the Script references

Comment: Added the missing lines. Both files are downloaded to the client browser.

Comment: do you have any script errors on page (check it on console)

Comment: Could you setup a JSFiddle?

Comment: Nope, just a warning:event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: here is the bootply to help : http://bootply.com/106537   - But it seems to work for me ( chromium-browser )

Comment: Thanx jahnux, in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/john_westhoff/gpXT7/ it works fine, as in youre bootply setup. Stange...I use chrome, visual studio .

Comment: After changing the included .js files to:   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
everuthing works as expected!!!

Comment: I'm glad for you. Can you include your answer as new answer and accept it ? ( in order to close it )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the .js references to:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
```

did the trick.